# Fastify - How to get non-file fields using fastify-multipart

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify, fastify-multipart

How to access text from request that are *non-file* fields? (I am using [Insomia](https://insomnia.rest/))

Our request using Insomia
[image]

We are able to access *file* fields by looping through parts. using `const parts = await req.files();`.

**index.js**

```js
    import Fastify from "fastify";
    import FastifyMultipart from "fastify-multipart";
    
    export const fastify = await Fastify();
    fastify.register(FastifyMultipart);
```

**controllers/property.js**

```js
    export const addProperty = async function (req, res) {
      try {
        // WE ACCESS FILES OF MULTIPART FORM REQUEST HERE
        const parts = await req.files();
        for await (const data of parts) {
          console.log("*******File being access**********");
          console.log(data.filename); // access file name
          ...
        }
        // HOW DO WE ACCESS OTHER *NON_FILES* FIELDS?
        ...
        res.status(201).send({ message: "Property Added!." });
      } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
      }
    };
```

in the controllers script we access *files* using `await req.files();`.

How do we access the fields that are *non-file*, like text

Comment: Maybe this answer can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981591/13199774

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to get other data it is given in the docs https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart

1. pass the other fields before file
   [image: Passing the name before image]

Now you can access name in data.fields

```
const data = await req.file();
console.log(data.fields.name.value); // virender
```

2. you can attach it to body

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-multipart'), { attachFieldsToBody: true });
const file = req.body.image1;
const name = req.body.name.value
```

Comment: FYI - for anyone interested - for option 2 - https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart#parse-all-fields-and-assign-them-to-the-body

Comment: And for option 1: `Note about data.fields: busboy consumes the multipart in serial order (stream). Therefore, the order of form fields is VERY IMPORTANT`